# Module not found: Can't resolve 'final-form' in '/app/node_modules/react-final-form/dist'

Tags: reactjs

./node_modules/react-final-form/dist/react-final-form.es.js

Module not found: Can't resolve 'final-form' in '/app/node_modules/react-final-form/dist'

Comment: the module is not installed, take a look to the documentation to know about the installing and usage guide https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/getting-started

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure you have installed the library

```
yarn add final-form react-final-form
```

2. And then you could import it like this.

```
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall final form using `npm install --save final-form react-final-form`